# Making @ModelAttribute annotation to accept form-data instead of x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am using spring webmvc for my project, and there i am using @ModelAttribute annotation in controller action to bind the form data to model. ModelAttribute is binding data fine if i am sending data in  x-www-form-urlencoded form.But if i am sending data in simple form-data then it is not binding.

I am sending request using POSTMAN Rest Client, below is the format of my request -

```
POST /register-school HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

testing@test.com
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

For this above request my ModelAttribute is not binding data to object.

But Its working if i am sending request in x-www-form-urlencoded

```
POST /register-school HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

email=testing%40test.com
```

**Is there is any way to make ModelAttribute to work with form-data also?**

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example where form-data fails.

Comment: I am testing my app with postMan , here is the preview of form-data request -POST /register-school HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="var2"

value1
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C